# Is there a way to upload a file via REST in Airflow via the SimpleHttpOperator?

Tags: airflow

I am trying to create an Airflow DAG to query some data, save it as CSV file and upload it to a REST API endpoint. I implemented this with a shell script and a CURL command like this:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://my.endpoint.com/automations-file-service/automations/fileupload/files' \
--header 'X-API-TOKEN: my_token' \
--form 'file=@/Users/myuser/myfiles/all_20200707_2.csv'
```

I am trying to move this to Airflow and want to convert that CURL command to Airflow via the SimpleHttpOperator. The issue is, I cannot find any parameter in the operator where I can add the path to the file, there is no "form" parameter. Has anyone implemented something like this in Airflow? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's no way to do this without providing or writing your own code. You have a couple ways to do this. Subclass the `SimpleHttpOperator` and rewrite the execute method such that you call the  `HttpHook` with the correct arguments. Subclass the `BaseOperator` for your specific case, and essentially do the  same. Or write the Python functionality into a Python Callable and use the `PythonOperator`.

### Detail

If you look up the [HttpHook](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.10/airflow/hooks/http_hook.py), you can see that the execution of the `SimpleHttpOperator`, largely just uses the Python requests library.

And the `run` method takes a `request_kwargs` option which you  can't access via the `execute` method on the `SimpleHttpOperator`. Writing an  operator with your own `execute` method or a Callable, you can expressly use `HttpHook.run(...)` to pass the arguments of your Request, or you can choose to use another Python http library.